# How to read the element count of stack allocated memory?

Tags: c#, stackalloc

Let's say I have just a pointer of previously stack allocated memory and I would like to know how many elements I have. How to do it?

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/stackalloc) says: "the use of `stackalloc` automatically enables buffer overrun detection features in the common language runtime" so I guess the size is kept somewhere.

Comment: Arrays hold their length as part of the data.

Comment: From C# 7.2 onwards, you'd probably use `Span` to encapsulate the block, and then you *do* have the length available (along with safe access): `Span<byte> b = stackalloc byte[100]; Console.WriteLine(b.Length);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you're looking for doesn't exist, it's your responsibility to keep track of this.

The buffer overrun detection doesn't check for out-of-bounds access on the "array" - there *is* no array. Instead, it uses a random value added *after* the allocated memory on the stack. In the function epilog, it checks if the value is still there - and if not, kills the whole process.

[Buffer overflow protection for stackalloc in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926021/buffer-overflow-protection-for-stackalloc-in-net)

Needless to say, this doesn't make it certain you don't suffer from a buffer overflow (or underflow, which is the main concern here). It just tries to limit its potential impact. In combination with keeping `stackalloc`ced locals in as small functions as possible, this serves as a pretty simple, while still quite effective, prevention of malicious code execution. You can still overwrite (or read) other locals, but you can't overwrite e.g. the function return pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I didn't know that's how this is handled.